# Why does grep -P on binary files sometimes match wrong bytes?

Tags: regex, shell, grep, binary, byte

I'm trying to use `grep -P` to find specific byte sequences in potentially large binary files. However, it sometimes matches where it shouldn't - for example, here's a golfed-down case where it appears to simply "match over" a wrong `\xc2` byte:

```
➜  alias bin2hex='xargs echo -n | od -An -tx1'

➜  echo -e '\x3e\x1f\xc2\x9d\xa0' > test.bin
➜  cat test.bin | bin2hex
 3e 1f c2 9d a0

➜  grep -P '\x1f\x9d' test.bin  
Binary file test.bin matches

➜  grep -Pao '\x1f\x9d' test.bin | bin2hex    
 1f c2 9d
```

Why does this happen?

And can it be avoided?

Comment: Search in GNU grep's manpage for 'binary'.

Comment: That only talks about the `--binary-files=text/binary` option (and its synonyms) - however, as I've  shown, the stated example incorrectly matches in *both* cases. (The `-P` case uses `binary`, while in the `-Pa` case uses `text`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command:

```
grep -P '\x1f\x9d' <<< $(echo -e '\x3e\x1f\xc2\x9d\xa0') | xargs echo -n | od -An -tx1
```

prints nothing with `grep` versions:

- GNU grep 2.5.1
- GNU grep 2.6.3
- GNU grep 2.21

Are you sure your `grep` is not aliased to anything wrong (`type grep`)?

---

<sup>*UPDATE: converting comments into answer*</sup>

I can reproduce your problem with a different `LANG` value:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8; grep -P '\x1f\x9d' <<< $(echo -e '\x3e\x1f\xc2\x9d\xa0')
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

The problem is not reproduced with:

```
LANG=en_US; grep -P '\x1f\x9d' <<< $(echo -e '\x3e\x1f\xc2\x9d\xa0')
```

Comment: "`grep is an alias for grep  --color=auto --exclude-dir={.bzr,.cvs,.git,.hg,.svn}`", but even when directly invoking `/usr/bin/grep` the problem persists. Your one-liner does print output for me. Grep version is "`(GNU grep) 2.21`". PCRE version is 8.37. OS is Arch Linux 64bit.

Comment: In my case, `grep -P '\x1f'` succeeds, however `grep -P '\x1f\x9d'` does not (all versions specified). Let's wait for some more feedback from users.

Comment: I think I may have found the issue! I use the `en_US.UTF-8` locale. When I run grep with `LC_ALL=C` it seems to behave like you say. Can you confirm?

Comment: What is your `LANG` env variable?

Comment: `en_US.UTF-8`, as are all the other vars listed by `locale`, except for `LC_ALL` which is unset.

Comment: My locale vars are all `en_US`, except for `LC_ALL` which is empty. I tried this: `LANG=en_US.UTF-8; grep -P '\x1f\x9d' <<< $(echo -e '\x3e\x1f\xc2\x9d\xa0')` and INDEED I have a match! At least now you have narrowed down the problem.